# Quasar app, missing some modules after npm install

Tags: vue.js, npm-install, quasar-framework

I created a quasar app with `quasar create`, then verified it works with `quasar dev`. Everything was fine.

But I wanted to upload the code to github to collaborate with other. So I created a repo and uploaded everything except node_modules and package-lock.json.

I then deleted my local repo and cloned the github repo to verify it was working correctly for others as well. I ran `npm install`, no error, and then `quasar dev`.

And here is my output :

```html
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

[  Error: Cannot find module '/home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/.postcssrc.js'
  Require stack:
  - /home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/inject.style-rules.js
  - /home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/create-chain.js
  - /home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/index.js
  - /home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/quasar-conf-file.js
  - /home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/bin/quasar-dev
  - /home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/bin/quasar
  - /usr/lib/node_modules/@quasar/cli/bin/quasar
  
  - loader:933 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15
  
  - loader:778 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27
  
  - loader:999 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19
  
  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18
  
  - inject.style-rules.js:117 create
    [xtreme-sports-app]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/inject.style-rules.js:117:27
  
  - inject.style-rules.js:41 injectRule
    [xtreme-sports-app]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/inject.style-rules.js:41:3
  
  - inject.style-rules.js:178 module.exports
    [xtreme-sports-app]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/inject.style-rules.js:178:3
  
  - create-chain.js:241 module.exports
    [xtreme-sports-app]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/create-chain.js:241:3
  
  - index.js:62 getSPA
    [xtreme-sports-app]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/index.js:62:17
  
  - index.js:229 module.exports
    [xtreme-sports-app]/[@quasar]/app/lib/webpack/index.js:229:18
  
] {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/inject.style-rules.js',
    '/home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/create-chain.js',
    '/home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/index.js',
    '/home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/quasar-conf-file.js',
    '/home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/bin/quasar-dev',
    '/home/th3g3ntl3man/github/xtreme-sports-app/node_modules/@quasar/app/bin/quasar',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/@quasar/cli/bin/quasar'
  ]
}

Node.js v17.1.0
```

I'm not sure if I did everything correctly but I can't find any answer about my issue...

Comment: Facing the same problem. Anyone got solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For me it's working after deleting yarn.lock and reinstall dependencies